# Socket.io emit event to array of users ids

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I implemented socket.io on my server, if user starts to follow another user just display notification to that specific user.

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('User connected')

  socket.on('joinRequest', (user, callback) => {
    socket.join(user.id);

    callback();
  });

  socket.on('followRequest', (agent, callback) => {

    io.to(agent.receiver).emit('newFollow', {
      from: agent.sender,
      to: agent.receiver
    })

    callback();
  })
})
```

As you can see every user is joined by his specific id.

```
 user: id,
 followers: [id, id, id, id...]
```

Then inside FollowSchema i have arrays of ids inside followers field.
How i can take all this ids and emit event to them when user create some post etc...
Like io.to([id, id, id]), i know it doesn't work that way but that's my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thing would work

```
Array.prototype.map.call(followers, id => {
      io.to(id).emit('event', data)
})
```